# Word meaning a place contains a lot of a certain type of people

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

Here's what I'm writing:

> The way I think it actually is - is that some companies are able to
>   attract and retain the good talent (through being able to pay well,
>   having interesting work, or being a [centrepoint] of talent).

What I'm getting at is that some companies contain a lot of talented people, and so people are going to want to work there, to be surrounded by them. What's a noun to describe a place this kind of place?

Comment: Have a look here:http://www.forbes.com/sites/dorieclark/2014/01/22/three-ways-your-company-can-attract-the-right-talent/

Answer (score 1):

> Some companies are a magnet for talent

would express the concept well if you mean to say they attract talented people.

> Some companies are a fertile breeding ground for talent

could be used if you mean to say that they produce a lot of talented people.

Comment: Neither of these quite capture what I'm trying to say. 

The first is simply tautological - 'Some companies attract talent through being a magnet for talent'. 

The second says that the company _produces_ talent, but that's not what's relevant here, what's relevant is that the company _already has_ a lot of a talent, and that's what people are attracted to.

Comment: Perhaps _sink_ could be a straight replacement for [centrepoint] but that still doesn't convey that the new talented staff are coming because there are a lot of talented staff already there. _Likeminded_ suggests people coming together through a common attribute. _Hub_, like _sink_, doesn't include the attraction element.

Answer (score 1):

The first word that came to my mind for this was "nexus." I think "showplace" or "haven" might also fit.

Comment: That said, I rather liked Frank's "magnet" answer, and your comment indicates that it's not what you're looking for. If my answer doesn't help you, I would appreciate an alternate example/explanation of what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

How about "**hive for talent**?"

> [**hive**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hive): a place filled with busy activity

Also, consider "**hub for talent**" and "**mecca for talent**."

> [**hub**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Hub): a center of activity or interest, a focal point
>
> [**mecca**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mecca): a place regarded as a center for a specified group, activity, or interest.

Answer (score 0):

**Synectics group**: [a group of people of varied background that meets to attempt creative solutions of problems through the unrestricted exercise of imagination and the correlation of disparate elements.](http://useful_english.enacademic.com/409273/synectics_group)

So 'synectics' is your noun

Answer (score 0):

A **congregation** is an option I considered.

> **Congregation** - a gathering or collection of people, animals, or things.