# Word for a place filled with unpleasant people

Tags: single-word-requests

I’m looking for a word that can be used in the following sentence:

“Many say that the industry is a ______ for/of narcissists.

Comment: What are the specific properties of this 'place' that make it more suitable for unpleasant people than for anyone else?

Comment: Quite possibly a duplicate of [word meaning a place contains a lot of a certain type of people](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/167155/word-meaning-a-place-contains-a-lot-of-a-certain-type-of-people/167159#167159). I'll not CV for a while in case better fits than 'magnet' / 'haven' / 'hub' / 'breeding ground' (all given at the possible dupe) are given.

Comment: How about "cesspool"?

Comment: Can you provide more context? *Magnet* (attraction) would convey a different sense than, say, *playground* (ownership / entitlement). Either way, the place is filled up with them.

Comment: @Cascabel - Problem is, I end up spending 10 minutes to find the Oxford definition (usually use Cambridge, but it didn't quite fit in this case), then I spent another 10 trying to get the bullet to format correctly.

Comment: Are you sure this *place* has to mean it's filled with bad people instead of simply being "____ of bad people?"

Answer (score 3):

*hotbed*

> 1. An environment conducive to vigorous growth or development, especially of something undesirable: a hotbed of intrigue.

From AHD https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=hotbed

There’s a difference between *hotbed of* and *hotbed for* captured in this definition.

Answer (score 3):

[cesspool](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/cesspool) seems like a good candidate:

1. a covered hole or container in the ground for collecting waste from a building, especially from the toilets
2. a place where dishonest or immoral people gather

   - a cesspool of corruption

Answer (score 2):

I suggest (from [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/breeding_ground))

> **breeding ground**
> <sub>NOUN</sub>
>
> **1.1** A place or situation that favours the development or occurrence of something.
> *The Web is indeed a modern-day breeding ground for unscrupulous forgers*

It is often (but not always) used in a negative sense, and you can say

> Many say that the industry is a breeding ground for narcissists.